# Localized routes and URL string

Tags: java, model-view-controller, localization, playframework, url-routing

Is there some common solution or best practice how to implement localized URL string and routes in (java) Play! application?

we need routes like this:

**/examples/demonstration**

**/esempi/dimostrazione**

**/przyklady/demonstracji**

...(10+ languages)

All URLs naturally pointing to controller **Examples** and action **demonstration**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typically you put a language code in there so that words that occur in different languages but with different meanings don't make your URL's ambiguous.  For example, `/en/once` might correspond to `/es/una_vez/` while `/es/once/` might correspond to the `/en/eleven/`.

Comment: Wait, in example above I tried to show that "example.com/examples/demonstration" should not be written like that in Polish version of the site. So links in application should be translated, containing translated routes but point to the same controller.

Comment: I realize that, but without a locale identifier, you will run into [false cognates](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/false_cognate).  Does `/once/` refer to the English word "once" or to the Spanish translation for `/eleven/`?

Comment: Ahh, you mean that, yes, I'll know users language from the cookie and chosen locale, but I could add language code at the begining. But is there some good solution of handling this kind of "hacking" the routes? Obviously I'll not use controller "En" or "Pl" instead of "Examples" and hope not write manually each route in 10 languages...

Comment: How are you receiving translations from translators?

Comment: Probably will have translated words in properties file similar to messages and other translations in Play! app.

Comment: Out of interest: why on earth would you ever need such a set-up? It completely contradicts the principle of a URL.

Comment: Which principle? Let's say that someone asked me to do because of comfort of our users, SEO and so on...

Comment: I like it, anyone have a good solution yet?  It would definitely be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can do something like this:

For English:

```
%{ if (play.i18n.Lang.getLocale().getLanguage().equals("en")) { }%
GET     /add-new-post                Application.addNewPost
%{ } }%
```

For Dutch:

```
%{ if (play.i18n.Lang.getLocale().getLanguage().equals("nl")) { }%
GET     /voeg-nieuwe-commentaar      Application.addNewPost
%{ } }%
```

Etc etc..

Credits: http://playframework.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/hidden-features-of-the-play-framework-routes-file/

Good luck

Comment: If nothing else I learned something new about routes :) Actually we decided to go "classic" way, like Joomla for example, you have "duplicated" content for each language, for pages/actions and for menus/controllers. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, please keep us somehow updated, because I'm planning to do similar project, where I need a minimum of 5 languages.. good luck!

Comment: This is great when the same code is deployed in multiple instances whith different language, but it does not work when there is support for multiple languages in the same Play instance.  I think the code in the routes files is only executed once when play starts, not every time a route is reversed (an URL is generated).